# Проблема к подключению к MySQL с Java

Tags: java, mysql

Пишу в `IntelliJ IDEA` переписал все с сайта с пояснениями, но ничего не работает.
Пытаюсь подключиться к Базе Данных на `MySQL ittrayvor` через `localhost` с портом `3307`, который стоит на сервере `MAMP`.

- Логин: `root`
- Пароль: `root`.

Вот код:

```
package com.Trayvor;
import java.sql.*;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to load class");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/ittrayvor";
        String USER = "root";
        String PASSWORD = "root";
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Вот ошибка, которая выдаеться:

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin\java.exe"
>   "-javaagent:C:\Programs\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition
>   2019.3.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=64310:C:\Programs\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath
>   "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Java_Practice\Java_General_Practice\out\production\Practice;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\mysql-connector-java-8.0.19\mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar"
>   com.Trayvor.Main Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is
>   deprecated. The new driver class is`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The
>   driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of
>   the driver class is generally unnecessary. java.sql.SQLException: The
>   server time zone value '��������� (����)' is unrecognized or
>   represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the
>   server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration
>   property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize
>   time zone support.    at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:76)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
>     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
>     at
>   java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
>     at
>   java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
>     at com.Trayvor.Main.main(Main.java:17) Caused by:
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The
>   server time zone value '��������� (����)' is unrecognized or
>   represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the
>   server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration
>   property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize
>   time zone support.    at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at
>   java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
>     at
>   java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:85)
>     at com.mysql.cj.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:132)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.configureTimezone(NativeProtocol.java:2118)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.initServerSession(NativeProtocol.java:2142)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1310)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:967)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826)
>     ... 6 more Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at com.Trayvor.Main.main(Main.java:22)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Я импортировал `JBDC` драйвер через `File>Project Structure в IntelliJ IDEA`

Comment: https://metanit.com/java/database/2.2.php

Comment: Alexander Chernin, после этого, у меня пишет connection failed!!! И Unknown database "название моей ДБ'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуете установить тайм зон.

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+8:00';
```

[Наглядно с видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_50AfOx8I6k)

[Подробное описание](https://overcoder.net/q/477/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81-mysql)

Comment: А где это прописывать?

Comment: необходимо выполнить sql запрос

Comment: Через плагин Database Navigator я смог подключиться, но при попытке подключения при запуске прораммы - та же ошибка.

Comment: посмотрите видео

Comment: Я по видео все и сделал.